# Range of Search Space for the hyperparameters of Support Vector Regresssion (SVR)

Tags: hyperparameter, libsvm

I need to know "what should be the practical range of c, gamma and epsilon hyper-parameters during grid search optimization in SVR".

The range of dependent variable lies between 1 to 300 with mean of 9 and std deviation of 15.